# Objective C++ call Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++, growl

I have a growl action I need to call from Objective C++

```
- (NSDictionary *) registrationDictionaryForGrowl {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Alert"], GROWL_NOTIFICATIONS_ALL,
            [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Alert"], GROWL_NOTIFICATIONS_DEFAULT
            , nil];
}
```

is the action in Objective C, but I need to put it in a `.mm` file (Objective C++) and I'm having a hard time trying to convert it properly because I need to put it inside a (C++) function inside a (C++) class.

Any idea how I could transfer this over to Objective C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather you want to provide a C++ object to Growl, which expects and Objective-C object. You can't do this.

Objective-C is a set of language extensions welded onto C. Objective-C++ is the result of welding exactly the same extensions onto C++. So in Objective-C++ you have both Objective-C style objects and C++ objects, and they are completely different things. One cannot be used when the other is expected. They have different ABIs, different schemes for resolving a method call/message send, different lifetime management, etc.

The purpose of Objective-C++ is not to make Objective-C objects and C++ objects compatible, but simply to make Objective-C code usable from C++ and C++ code usable from Objective-C++.

So what you could do is create your C++ class that you want to use as a delegate, and then create an Objective-C++ class that wraps your C++ class and has methods that simply forward to an instance of your C++ class.

```
class Foo {
    int bar(int i) { return i+1; }
};

@interface ObjCFoo : NSObject
{
    Foo foo;
}

- (int) bar:(int) i;
@end

@implementation ObjFoo
- (int) bar:(int) i;
{
    return foo.bar(i);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C++ there are C++ classes and Objective-C classes. There are no Objective-C++ classes. The `GrowlApplicationBridgeDelegate` which implements `registrationDictionaryForGrowl` has to be an Objective-C object. You can define it exactly same in an .mm file as you would in an .m file. The only difference is that in your .mm file the Objective-C classes you define can call and use C++ classes and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what do you call Objective-C++, but the code above, provided it is in an Objective-C `@implementation` section, will compile fine with or without Objective-C++ enabled (`.m` or `.mm` extension).

By the way, if you are using Xcode 4.4 or above, the following will do as well:

```
- (NSDictionary*) registrationDictionaryForGrowl {
    return @{
        GROWL_NOTIFICATIONS_ALL : @[ @"Alert" ],
        GROWL_NOTIFICATIONS_DEFAULT : @[ @"Alert" ] };
}
```

Comment: I need to put it in a C++ class and function. Can I just put the @implementation at the top then throw it in the C++ class and function? I also thought the `- ...` couldn't be thrown in a function?

Comment: I have no idea why you need to do that. But Growl is implemented in ObjC and expects the delegate to be an ObjC instance. You cannot provides Growl with a C++ instance. That said, you can use ObjC instances in C++ instances and vice et versa. Point is, there is no toll free bridge between C++ and ObjC objects.